# Dagger2 generated classes are not accessible in Android < 5.0

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a project that uses Dagger2 and it's complement Autodagger. My main test devices are Genymotion emulators loaded with KitKat and Lollipop and I switch between them indistinctively.

Yesterday I found out that running the project on either emulator or a real device with 4.x causes the following exception as soon as the app launches:

```
   11-20 15:36:31.637 7189-7189/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:   com.chiskosystems.debito.DebitoAppModule_ProvideRestAdapterFactory 
    at com.chiskosystems.debito.DaggerDebitoAppComponent.initialize(DaggerDebitoAppComponent.java:30)
    at com.chiskosystems.debito.DaggerDebitoAppComponent.<init>(DaggerDebitoAppComponent.java:19)
    at com.chiskosystems.debito.DaggerDebitoAppComponent.<init>(DaggerDebitoAppComponent.java:11)
    at com.chiskosystems.debito.DaggerDebitoAppComponent$Builder.build(DaggerDebitoAppComponent.java:72)
    at com.chiskosystems.debito.DebitoApp.setupComponent(DebitoApp.java:130)
    at com.chiskosystems.debito.DebitoApp.onCreate(DebitoApp.java:75)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:999)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1255)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

but a

```
find /path/to/project -name DebitoAppModule_ProvideRestAdapterFactory.java
```

shows a result. Also, the project runs fine in L and M.

## proguard-rules

```
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
-keepclassmembers

-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes InnerClasses

-keep class org.eclipse.mat.** { *; }
-keep class com.squareup.leakcanary.** { *; }
```

## Build warnings   *(these are only a portion)*

```
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf$1: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.login.LoginResult
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf$1: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.FacebookException
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf$1: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.AccessToken
Note: com.google.android.gms.internal.zzlf$2: can't find dynamically referenced class com.facebook.SessionState
Note: com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzy: can't find dynamically referenced class com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl
Note: com.google.gson.internal.UnsafeAllocator: can't find dynamically referenced class sun.misc.Unsafe
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class android.net.TrafficStats
Note: com.squareup.okhttp.internal.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class android.net.Network
Note: retrofit.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class android.os.Build
Note: retrofit.Platform: can't find dynamically referenced class rx.Observable
Note: android.support.multidex.MultiDexExtractor accesses a method 'apply()' dynamically
Note: android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompatJellybean accesses a declared field 'icon' dynamically
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.design.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat$Action { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'android.support.v7.mediarouter.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.chiskosystems.debito.R$attr { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'com.chiskosystems.debito.R$id { int icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.AppRequestData { io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.IconRequest icon; }'
      Maybe this is program field 'io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.AppSettingsData { io.fabric.sdk.android.services.settings.AppIconSettingsData icon; }'
```

I'm using

```
compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

apt 'com.github.lukaspili.autodagger2:autodagger2-compiler:1.1'
compile 'com.github.lukaspili.autodagger2:autodagger2:1.1'
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
```

Switching build tools has not helped either. Any pointer to what can be wrong are greatly appreciated

## EDIT

These started appearing and they are constant in each build:

```
/home/chisko/AndroidStudioProjects/Debito/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/chiskosystems/debito/ui/activities/activity/DaggerMainActivityComponent.java
Warning:(54, 75) [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method create in class MainActivity_MembersInjector is applied to given types
required: MembersInjector<BaseActivity>,Provider<MainActivityPresenter>
found: MembersInjector,Provider<MainActivityPresenter>
Warning:(54, 76) [unchecked] unchecked conversion
required: MembersInjector<BaseActivity>
found:    MembersInjector
Warning:(54, 75) [unchecked] unchecked conversion
required: MembersInjector<MainActivity>
found:    MembersInjector
/home/chisko/AndroidStudioProjects/Debito/app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/chiskosystems/debito/ui/activities/splash/DaggerLoginActivityComponent.java
Warning:(54, 77) [unchecked] unchecked method invocation: method create in class LoginActivity_MembersInjector is applied to given types
required: MembersInjector<BaseActivity>,Provider<LoginPresenter>
found: MembersInjector,Provider<LoginPresenter>
Warning:(54, 78) [unchecked] unchecked conversion
required: MembersInjector<BaseActivity>
found:    MembersInjector
Warning:(54, 77) [unchecked] unchecked conversion
required: MembersInjector<LoginActivity>
found:    MembersInjector
```

Comment: Does this happen on dagger version 2.0.2 as well? Have you tried removing individual proguard rules? What happens if you use the `dontoptimize` flag in proguard?

Comment: Yes, this happens with 2.0.2 as well. I'm not sure Proguard is to blame. The project used to run fine last week, without having added anything to PG for a while. This is a very strange issue, because now my project won't even compile with a GC overhead limit reached exception :(

Comment: Looks like I was having JVM issues, which are fixed now. After two days of changing libraries, Proguard configs, cloning repo to a clean directory, and even cleaning every bit of AS in my machine I'm back to the point where generated code is the culprit. I added ```dontoptimize``` with same results, with Dagger2.0.2. Please also note that the error is shown for all my dependencies listed on the AppModule: I have four classes there and the crash happens randomly between one of them, not only on one.

Comment: What happens if you disable proguard and use Multidex?

Comment: I will at some point need to enable it for code protection when we go live. And I added multidex a few weeks ago.

Comment: I tried anyhow disabling PG, still no luck

Comment: Me too facing the same issue. Did you got any solution for the same?

Comment: Did you check the proguard output or mapping file for anything relevant?

Comment: From @Cheskos

`I'm not sure of how to interpret the mapping so we can debug this, but here's a piece for one of the classes: chiskosystems.debito.modules.DebitoAppModule_ProvideRestAdapterFactory -> com.chiskosystems.debito.b.e: com.chiskosystems.debito.modules.DebitoAppModule module -> b boolean $assertionsDisabled -> a void <init>(com.chiskosystems.debito.modules.DebitoAppModule) -> <init> retrofit.RestAdapter get() -> a dagger.internal.Factory create(com.chiskosystems.debito.modules.DebitoAppModule) -> a java.lang.Object get() -> b void <clinit>() -> <clinit> `

Comment: ^ (on an answer I deleted that was intended to be a comment)

I'm not sure the best way to help on this asynchronously, but it that looks like your factory is being renamed to com.chiskosystems.debito.b.e. you could try and check via reflection if that class is available in your app, if so that would mean part of your code is getting proguarded and another part is not. If that's not the case, is it possible that your stack trace is deobfuscated? How do you have the full class name in your stack trace?

Comment: Hmmm no, the stacktrace looks clean. Sorry if I didn't clarify this, but this app hasn't go live yet and I've been running debug the whole time, with PG disabled. Also, I think that the fact that it runs fine in 5.0 and upwards but doesn't even start in 4.x completely leaves PG out of the equation, or am I wrong?

Comment: hey fella @PravinsinghWaghela have you found a solution yet? Not me :(

Comment: Any news? I'm trying to migrate my multi-module + dagger2 project to also use kotlin and am currently observing exactly(?) this issue. On my physical Android 4.2 I get `NoClassDefFound` but thanks to your issue I checked on an AVD where it runs! Thanks for making me try this.